# "Unable to log in with provided credentials" on HEROKU but not LOCALHOST

Tags: python, django, authentication, heroku

I have been working on a Django app on localhost and got the site where I was ready to push to Heroku.

While running the site on localhost, I am able to successfully get an Auth Token from my internal API, and log the user in successfully.

The moment I try to do this same action on the Heroku site, I get the error

```
"Unable to log in with provided credentials."
```

I am not sure why this is happening, maybe there is something specific to Heroku?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'widget_tweaks',
    'django_filters',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',

    'admin_settings',
    'customer_settings',
    'user',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'admin_settings.User'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

Comment: I assume you did migrations on heroku as well and create superuser?

Comment: A bit more explanation of the previous comment: your local database and your Heroku database are entirely separate. Deploying to Heroku doesn't copy your database; you need to create your schema (`heroku run python manage.py migrate`) and create data (probably starting with `heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser`).

Comment: Sorry fellas, my mistake was with the RDS security, my ingress was being blocked since the wizard used my personal IP. The solution was to unblock ingress IP. Thank you for your time though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my AWS security.

Ingress access was limited to my personal IP address by default, I simply had to remove this limitation and the system starts working just fine.

If you are able to access your RDS from localhost, but not on Heroku, this will solve your problem since AWS uses your IP address during the setup wizard to block all other connections.